# arctan function with cordic with vhdl

Tags: vhdl, division, fpga, cordic

I want to design arctan function with VHDL for using in demodulator design. I need a division & arctan function block. I have two signals, assumed that sin(alpha) and cos(alpha) from previos blocks. I want to retrieve alpha with using division [sin(alpha)/cos(alpha) = tan(alpha)] and then arctan function. I found that it is possible to do that with cordic algortihm, but a bit confused. Do you have any recommendation, docs or sth. how to design division & arctan with cordic in vhdl?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a CORDIC arctan function, no need for division. CORDIC arctan takes cartesian coordinates `(X, Y)` and convert it to polar coordinates `(r, theta)`. You want *theta*.

You can look at wikipedia for details of the algorithm. Your fpga vendor should already provide CORDIC IP core for free, for instance, here [the one for Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/cordic/v6_0/pg105-cordic.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative implementation is to use a memory: the tangent is the address and the angle is the contents at that address. That will be practical for a lowish number of bits, but obviously not once the number of bits gets higher. It depends on how many bits resolution you need.